# How to cherry pick tuned parameters after workflow_map

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, data-science, tidymodels

I've tuned succesfully several models using `{tidymodels}` and `{workflow_set}`. However, when testing the validation dataset with `tune::last_fit()`, the parameters obtained by `tune::select_best` don't behave well. This makes me want to manually test other sets of parameters on the validation set. I find `tune::show_best()` and `tune::select_best()` very limited for doing so, since they only consider one metric when choosing the right parameters. I've managed to filter the tibbles with a more complex logic involving several metrics using pure `{dplyr}` but this is not optimal and is time consuming, involving manually finalizing each model every time I want to test one of the models.

Is there a way to cherry pick a set of parameters based on the workflow_id and .config data of the tibble?

It would be really helpful that `tune::select_best()` could take more conditions to pick a model.

This is the classical process to get the "best" set of parameters (which unfortunately is not in my case since I get a model with a very high roc_auc but very bad spec for example).

```
models_tuned <- models %>% 
  workflow_map("tune_bayes",
               resamples = cv_folds,
               initial = 20,
               iter= 10,
               metrics = mm_metrics,
               verbose = TRUE)

best_results <- models_tuned %>% 
  extract_workflow_set_result(id = "norm_nnet") %>% 
  select_best(metric = "accuracy")

fitted_workflow <- models_tuned %>%
  extract_workflow(id = "norm_nnet") %>%
  finalize_workflow(best_results) %>% 
  last_fit(split=split_df,
           metrics=mm_metrics)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-any-other-tool-to-extract-parameter-sets-after-tuning-besides-select-best/165367/2):

You can pass any parameters you want to [`finalize_workflow()`](https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/finalize_model.html). The `parameters` argument takes any tibble that includes values for the tuning parameters.

There are also other `select_*()` functions to use as well as the unreleased [desirability2](https://github.com/tidymodels/desirability2) package.

> I get a model with a very high roc_auc but very bad spec for example

That sounds like a class imbalance. You might look into using a cost-sensitive learning method or rebalance (perhaps with [themis](https://themis.tidymodels.org)).